# How to use an IF else statement in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to run a simple IF else statement so that when the user enters a number (such as a Game ID), the web page evaluates which game title to show.  I have two problems. A) An answer appears to flash on screen and then disappears? B) I don't want to click a button to call the function that sets this process in motion. Instead, I want the user to enter the Game ID and the title of the game to automatically appear or not.Even better, is there a way of typing in an ID number and then the web page will see if the info appears in a spreadsheet?

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="GameID">Game ID:</label></td>
    <td><input name="GameID" type="text" id="GameID" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="195" align="right"><button onclick="myFunction()">Search Game</button></td>
    <td id="GameName" type="text" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var GameName;
        if (GameID == 1) {
            GameName = "Fantasy World";
        } else if (GameID == 2) {
            GameName = "Sir Wags A Lot";
        } else {
            GameName = "Take a Path";
        }
    document.getElementById("GameName").innerHTML = GameName;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the values, instead of comparing them. Use '==' instead of '='.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Also, keep in mind that Java and JavaScript are not related.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the values with `=`. Use operator `==` to compare.

Change the comparison to `if (GameID == 1)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now changed the script but still no luck - do you have any further suggestions about why I might be going wrong. Clearly, I am very new to all of this.